# Python SQLITE insert into not working

Tags: python, sqlite

So I am trying to get a simple program to insert information into a sqlite db.

The line that is breaking is the cur.execute

```
sitename = "TEST sitename2"
siteusername = "TEST siteusername2"
sitepasswd = "TEST sitepassword2"
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(sitename, siteusername, sitepasswd) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", (sitename, siteusername, sitepasswd))
```

Error that I receive from Python:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Comment: Pastebin for complete code:  http://pastebin.com/GF12ty6g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have the wrong parameter style.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.paramstyle
'qmark'
```

Change your code to:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable(sitename, siteusername, sitepasswd) 
               VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (sitename, siteusername, sitepasswd))
```

Comment: Wow that worked! In 3 minutes once it unlocks I will mark this as correct.  Thanks so much.  Its always the small issues...